# How do I check for an empty scalar in Perl?

Tags: perl

How do I check for an empty scalar in perl? If I have no `$list`, I do not want to send an email.

Can I check for empty message in the send_email routine or do this outside?

I have a query that uses [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm).

```
my $servSet = $wmiObj->ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE DisplayName LIKE 'ServiceNameHere%'", "WQL",  wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);
```

I'm looping through it here and building a list `$list`

```
foreach my $serv (in $servSet) {
    next if $serv->{started}; 
    my $sname  = $serv->{name};
    my $sstate = $serv->{started};
    my $ssmode = $serv->{startmode};
    $list .= "Service: $sname  - $sstate - $ssmode\n";  
 }
```

I use the $list to send as body of the email:

```
sub send_email {
...
..
$smtp->datasend($list);
..
.                        
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Perl, `undef`, `""` (and also `0` and `"0"`) evaluate to "false". So you can just do a boolean test:

```
send_email() if $list;
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't like to fool around with what's actually in the variable. If I want to see if anything, anything at all, is in a scalar, I check its length:

```
 send_mail() if length $scalar;
```

Comment: This is optimal.  Doing `send_mail() if $scalar;` confuses 0, '' (empty string), and undef.  Perhaps you would want to send a '0' if there's a 0.  We see a commonly poorly written idiom: `while( <> ) { chomp; next unless $_; # ... }` but that skips lines that evaluate to false while containing some value.  `length` is a better test.  It evaluates to true if there is "something" in the scalar, and false if the scalar contains '' (empty string, which is nothing) or undef (undefined).  Sometimes being too clever (ie, too terse) gets us in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 if (!($list eq ""))
     send_email(...);
```

or

```
 if ($list ne "")
     send_email(...);
```